# How to return a new object of a defined subclass in return statement

Tags: python, class, return

I'm trying to get in return statement a new object of a defined class, but I am having difficulties while using the return statement. What I should get is a new object by calling the constructor in the same return statement
passing as arguments those that require the constructor. Considering that the constructor of each class is the name of the class.

THis is what I have so far:

```
def complementary(self):
     complementary = ''.join([DNA.bases_complementary[base] for base in self.get_sequence()])
     return complementary
```

But it just return a string which is something obvious, but it is possible to return this string as a new object of the subclass DNA (The superclass is SEQUENCE).
My SuperClass is this:

```
class SEQUENCE:
    def __init__(self, sequence):
        self.__sequence = sequence
        length = len(sequence) 
    def __str__(self):
        st =  'The introduced sequence is: {0}\n'.format(self.__sequence)
        st = st + 'The length of the sequence is: {0}\n'.format(len(self.__sequence))
        return st

    def get_sequence(self):
        return self.__sequence
```

My DNA subclass is this:

```
class DNA(SEQUENCE):
    bases = {'A','T', 'C','G'} 
    complementary_bases = {'A':'T', 'T':'A', 'C':'G','G':'C'}
    transcription = {'A':'U', 'T':'A', 'C':'G','G':'C'}

    def __init__(self, sequence):
        super().__init__(sequence)
        self.__length = len(sequence)
        bases = {'A','T','C','G'}
        sequence_set = set(sequence)
        if sequence_set <= bases: 
            print('The introduced sequence is', sequence, 'with the following length',len(sequence))
        else: 
            print('INCORRECT DNA SEQUENCE')
            raise NameError('SequenceError')
```

Comment: What is an example of the return string from `complimentaria`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return DNA(complementary)
```

Comment: it returns this:The introduced sequence is 'sequence' the length of the sequence is 'length'  <__main__.DNA object at 0x000001CCC02F4EB8>, as far as i am concerned return an DNA object but the sentence  " <__main__.DNA object at 0x000001CCC02F4EB8>" what actually means?

Comment: <__main__.DNA object at 0x000001CCC02F4EB8> is the object you wanted and "The introduced sequence is 'sequence' the length of the sequence is 'length'" is the output of that object as you coded it in __init__()

Comment: If x = DNA('ACTGGT') and I call the x.complentary() it returns the new object as DNA but when i call the x.get_sequence() it return as the previous one, I mean it returns the original x instead of the complementary sequence. Is that normal?